Differential pair output of an ADC is routed in an opposite manner to an FMC connector
I have designed a 16 channel ADC card.
The part number of the ADC chip is ADC3444.
I have routed the digital outputs(differential signals) to an FMC connector on Board.
The mistake i have done is, in one of the ADC chips, one of the differential digital output pairs is routed in an opposite manner in the FMC connector. The positive of the differential pair output from ADC chip is routed to the negative pin in the FMC connector and vice-versa.
The digital output signals from the on-board FMC connector will be connected to another board in which there is FPGA. The digital outs will be sent to the FPGA.
If we were to use a wiring cable to connect the signals from one board to another board. We could have swapped the wires. But that is not the case. Another PCB with FPGA and mating FMC connector will be placed directly on top of my board.
How can I rectify this issue and how can i make the board work. Kindly, suggest.

It is very common to reverse pairs to simplify routing on dense boards. You just need to flip the bits on the FPGA. Be sure to document the flip on your schematics though!

The only impact that swapping the P and N signals will have (applies to CML, LVDS, PECL, and many more differential standards) is that the receiver will see the signal inverted (0's become 1's and vice versa).
Fortunately you are feeding the signal into an FPGA, which means correcting this is simple, you just invert the received signal within the FPGA.
Depending on the FPGA capabilities, some can invert the signal before any deserialisation is performed (i.e. optional not gate in the IO buffer). Otherwise lack this IO buffer invert, at which point you simply invert all bits in the parallel data bus after deserialisation (*).

(*) If performing link training (word alignment) using a fixed pattern , and the alignment logic in the FPGA comes before you can invert the data, you would also have to invert the training pattern.
